# How to add new "Platform" in Jira?

Tags: jira

Need to add a new item is drop down in Jira. Did not found, searched for long time.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a custom field. Jira admins can change them

Answer (score 0):

Unless this field comes from a plugin (Jira Server) or addon (Jira Cloud) it is a custom field. You will need admin permissions to configure a field. To add another option navigate to "Custom Fields" page, locate "Platform" field and choose a **cog icon > Configure** then click the **Options** or **Edit Options** link and you will be able to add new options there. Not sure which Jira version you are using, [here you have a documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/configuring-a-custom-field-802592532.html#Configuringacustomfield-options) for this for Jira 7.1.